# Delete records when the difference in days between two dates is greater than a certain value in java

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I need to delete records when the difference between SYSDATE and insertDate(field of my table with timestamp(6) format) is greater than 20 days.
I tried the following:

```
String myQuery = "delete from STUDENT where SYSDATE - insertDate > INTERVAL '20' DAY";
session.createQuery(myQuery).executeUpdate();
```

but I get this error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: 20 near line 1
```

after this query I create a Criteria to retrieve the list of remaining students. is this the best way to delete records? or should i use Criteria? if so how? thanks

Comment: What DB is this?

Comment: I'm hearing the oracle DB

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
String myQuery = "delete from STUDENT where (SYSDATE - insertDate) > 20";
session.createQuery(myQuery).executeUpdate();
```

Comment: insertDate is of type TIMESTAMP (6) so the difference in this way is not good. I modify my question by specifying the format.

Comment: @Fesilox then use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead of `SYSDATE`, you will get an output of this format : `10 19:30:0.0`, where 10 is the difference in days and the other part are the hours.

Comment: I get the following error: SQL error: inconsistent data types: expected INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND, got NUMBER

Comment: Try this `delete from STUDENT where (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - (TO_TIMESTAMP(insertDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))) > 20`

Comment: I guess the format you are using for the column `timestamp` is not the same with the one returned from `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: unfortunately also in this way the same error is generated